# Auto Re-sizing BG and black bottom bar

Tags: html, xhtml, css

I am trying to think of some way to have both, however I cant figure out how.

I had a black bar at the bottom of the page fixed, using:

```
body {
    background-image:url(../images/bottom_black.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px 800px;
}
```

Works fine, but I also want a radial gradient bg, so I made one and placed this code to make it auto re-sizing for different resolutions:

```
html {
    background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

They each work great on their own but not together. I know they are both background images and that is why but there has to be some work around. Please help!

Here are the test links:

[Re-Size BG](http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/gm_2012/index.html)

[Black Bottom](http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/gm_2012/index2.html)

Comment: Why not just add a covering div with position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width:100%; Then add the black bottom background to that div?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
html {
    background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
    -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
    -o-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```